# how to use GraphQL from Java?

Tags: java, rest, graphql, graphql-java

Any webservice which supports [GraphQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphQL) is consumable through a Java [implementation](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphql-java/graphql-java)?  Because "it provides an alternative to REST..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

graphql-java (that you linked to) is an implementation of the GraphQL specification. As such, it is used to create GraphQL *servers*.
A client doesn't need anything special to consume a service, just like it doesn't need anything special to consume a REST service - only to be be able to speak HTTP. **You can use any generic HTTP client you like**.

But! There is a number of dedicated GraphQL clients that make it more convenient (copied from my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57404560/294657)):

1. [Spring's GraphQL client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/reference/client.html) - Dynamic client (with optional response-to-POJO mapping)
2. [SmallRye GraphQL](https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-graphql-client) - Offers both a dynamic and a typesafe client
3. [Netflix DGS client](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/advanced/java-client/) - Has both a simple and a type-safe client
4. [Apollo Kotlin](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/) - Generates Kotlin and Java models from GraphQL queries.
5. There's a Node based Java client generator and a [Maven plugin](https://github.com/Sparow199/apollo-client-maven-plugin) for it too.
6. [Nodes](https://github.com/americanexpress/nodes)
7. [Shopify's GraphQL code gen](https://github.com/Shopify/graphql_java_gen) - Needs (J)Ruby to run but generates Java code.
8. [Manifold](https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold/tree/master/manifold-deps-parent/manifold-graphql) can be used as a GraphQL client

These are all different beasts, as you'll see, so you'll have to decide what fits.