# GraphQL implimentation with Shopify using Java

Tags: java, shopify, graphql, shopify-app, graphql-java

I am building a Shopify app which needs to adjust inventory of products in Shopify. Shopify is about to deprecate its inventory adjustment POST call using `admin/product.json` and will updated to `/admin/inventory_levels/adjust.json`, but the new inventory adjustment POST call allows to update only single inventory level at a time.
But my app needs to update multiple inventory levels at some particular point of time, so doing POST call for every individual inventory level will be resource taking and time consuming. When I contacted a Shopify Expert, he recommended me to use GraphQL for the above purpose. I researched for GraphQL + Shoipfy implementation in Java but did not find satisfactory results, so I need help in implementing Client POST call of GraphQL in Java .
Below is my structure of GraphQL, I want to implement in Java

```
mutation {
  item1: inventoryAdjustQuantity(input: {inventoryLevelId: "gid://shopify/InventoryLevel/9229566067?inventory_item_id=10588945219699", availableDelta: 3}) {
    inventoryLevel {
      available
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
  item2: inventoryAdjustQuantity(input: {inventoryLevelId: "gid://shopify/InventoryLevel/9229762675?inventory_item_id=10588945219699", availableDelta: 3}) {
    inventoryLevel {
      available
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
  item3: inventoryAdjustQuantity(input: {inventoryLevelId: "gid://shopify/InventoryLevel/9229926515?inventory_item_id=10588945219699", availableDelta: 3}) {
    inventoryLevel {
      available
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
  item4: inventoryAdjustQuantity(input: {inventoryLevelId: "gid://shopify/InventoryLevel/9645391987?inventory_item_id=10588945219699", availableDelta: 3}) {
    inventoryLevel {
      available
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
  item5: inventoryAdjustQuantity(input: {inventoryLevelId: "gid://shopify/InventoryLevel/9645457523?inventory_item_id=10588945219699", availableDelta: 3}) {
    inventoryLevel {
      available
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
  item6: inventoryAdjustQuantity(input: {inventoryLevelId: "gid://shopify/InventoryLevel/9645490291?inventory_item_id=10588945219699", availableDelta: 3}) {
    inventoryLevel {
      available
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
  item7: inventoryAdjustQuantity(input: {inventoryLevelId: "gid://shopify/InventoryLevel/9229566067?inventory_item_id=10588945252467", availableDelta: 3}) {
    inventoryLevel {
      available
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
  item8: inventoryAdjustQuantity(input: {inventoryLevelId: "gid://shopify/InventoryLevel/9229762675?inventory_item_id=10588945252467", availableDelta: 3}) {
    inventoryLevel {
      available
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
  item9: inventoryAdjustQuantity(input: {inventoryLevelId: "gid://shopify/InventoryLevel/9229926515?inventory_item_id=10588945252467", availableDelta: 3}) {
    inventoryLevel {
      available
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
  item10: inventoryAdjustQuantity(input: {inventoryLevelId: "gid://shopify/InventoryLevel/9645391987?inventory_item_id=10588945252467", availableDelta: 3}) {
    inventoryLevel {
      available
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

It would be great if you will help me with this issue or will guide me to some resourceful link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use GraphQL from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50664293/how-to-use-graphql-from-java)

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered multiple times. In short, look for Shopify's Graphql Java Generator or Apollo Android (not Android-specific, despite the name).

Answer (score 0):

You can use graphql admin app to run you queries in app. It is very good app it also help you to find the parameters as well as identify you error in query.
https://shopify-graphiql-app.shopifycloud.com/login

You can also visit document to describe how we can use insomnia -> graphql learning kit. Where you need import the collection. I am using this tool to run graphql.
https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/shopify-graphql-learning-kit