# Is there a recommended library for building GraphQL queries?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I'm calling a service that exposes a GraphQL interface. So I'm able to post a GraphQL query and receive data back via curl. Now I want to write a service that builds the query for me (dynamically, based on query parameters I send my endpoint) and sends the request and gets the response back.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.4.

I know you can build queries with the elastic search library in Spring. Wondering if there's something similar for GraphQL.

Comment: In my view this is a legitimate question. The author simply asks how one can build GraphQL queries in Spring Boot.  The question is also clear in its purpose, it's not asking for the best tool, just if there's a solution out there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few clients, taking rather different approaches.

1. [Spring's GraphQL client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/reference/client.html) - Dynamic client (with optional response-to-POJO mapping)
2. [SmallRye GraphQL](https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-graphql-client) - Offers both a dynamic and a typesafe client
3. [Netflix DGS client](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/advanced/java-client/) - Has both a simple and a type-safe client
4. [Apollo Kotlin](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/) - Generates Kotlin and Java models from GraphQL queries.
5. There's a Node based Java client generator and a [Maven plugin](https://github.com/Sparow199/apollo-client-maven-plugin) for it too.
6. [Nodes](https://github.com/americanexpress/nodes)
7. [Shopify's GraphQL code gen](https://github.com/Shopify/graphql_java_gen) - Needs (J)Ruby to run but generates Java code.
8. [Manifold](https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold/tree/master/manifold-deps-parent/manifold-graphql) can be used as a GraphQL client

These are all different beasts, as you'll see, so you'll have to decide what fits.

Comment: This is an excellent starting point. Thanks

Comment: @GLor Did you manage to use any client and generate a query?If yes please share some code.