# How to make a call to a GraphQL endpoint from a Java application

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I am trying to make a call to a GraphQL endpoint (external, not controlled by me), all I can find on internet is how to setup a back-end GraphQL endpoint using Java Spring Boot. How do I call a GraphQL endpoint from a Java application?

Comment: I think you just send the query to the endpoint as text.

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57404560/294657) for a list of available clients

Answer (score 5):

Netflix DGS has springboot client libraries .

Ref : https://netflix.github.io/dgs/advanced/java-client/#http-client-wrapper

and

https://netflix.github.io/dgs/generating-code-from-schema/#generating-client-apis.

```
private RestTemplate dgsRestTemplate;

private static final String URL = "http://someserver/graphql";

private static final String QUERY = "{\n" +
            "  ticks(first: %d, after:%d){\n" +
            "    edges {\n" +
            "      node {\n" +
            "        route {\n" +
            "          name\n" +
            "          grade\n" +
            "          pitches\n" +
            "          location\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "        \n" +
            "        userStars\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}";

public List<TicksConnection> getData() {
    DefaultGraphQLClient graphQLClient = new DefaultGraphQLClient(URL);
    GraphQLResponse response = graphQLClient.executeQuery(query, new HashMap<>(), (url, headers, body) -> {
        /**
         * The requestHeaders providers headers typically required to call a GraphQL endpoint, including the Accept and Content-Type headers.
         * To use RestTemplate, the requestHeaders need to be transformed into Spring's HttpHeaders.
         */
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.forEach(requestHeaders::put);

        /**
         * Use RestTemplate to call the GraphQL service. 
         * The response type should simply be String, because the parsing will be done by the GraphQLClient.
         */
        ResponseEntity<String> exchange = dgsRestTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity(body, requestHeaders), String.class);

        /**
         * Return a HttpResponse, which contains the HTTP status code and response body (as a String).
         * The way to get these depend on the HTTP client.
         */
        return new HttpResponse(exchange.getStatusCodeValue(), exchange.getBody());
    }); 

    TicksConnection ticks = graphQLResponse.extractValueAsObject("ticks", TicksConnection.class);
    return ticks;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, when I added `graphql-dgs-spring-boot-starter` this dependency and then trying to create instance of `DefaultGraphQLClient ` its says cannot resolve symbol. Can you please help what I am missing here?

Comment: Add the com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-spring-boot-starter dependency to your Gradle or Maven configuration and import the class as  for any other java. Ref : https://netflix.github.io/dgs/getting-started/ . Appreciate if you could  mark the above as useful (UP) and if its correct choose as the right answer.

Comment: now I am getting this error ` Error creating bean with name 'schema' defined in class path resource [com/netflix/graphql/dgs/autoconfig/DgsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type graphql.schema.GraphQLCodeRegistry not present
`. This was working couple of mins ago...Now I started getting this error

Comment: for client purpose just `graphql-dgs-client` dependency is needed